# Error while uploading image on imgur via CURL

Tags: bash, curl, imgur

I am trying to upload an image on imgur by accessing their API through CURL. I tried:

```
curl -d "image=reddit.png" -d "key=myapikey" http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json
```

It raised a famous error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Image format not supported, or image is corrupt.","request":"\/\/2\/upload.json","method":"post","format":"json","parameters":"image = reddit.png, key = myapikey"}}
```

I am also facing the same issue while writing a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash 

API_KEY="myapikey"                                                                                                                                            
file="$1"                                                                                                                                      

output=$(curl -d "image=$file" -d "key=$API_KEY" http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json)                                                           

echo $output
```

The ouytput is the same error message as above. I tried it with `jpg/png` both format raised the same error.

So, any idea what am I doing wrong here.

PS: My imnage is not corrupt and I am executing the script/command from the same directory which contains the image.

Comment: I don't think `-d "image=reddit.png"` is the right way to use the [imgur API](http://api.imgur.com/) with curl.

Comment: @Tichodroma: But in an example they are using [-d "image=reddit.png"](http://api.imgur.com/examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ curl -d "image=@reddit.png" ...
```

See [the manpage of curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for details and read the description of the `-d --data` option.

**Edit:**

To encode an image, use the [`base64` utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/base64):

```
$ base64 reddit.png > reddit.base64.png
```

Comment: The man page mentions that `contents of file must be url-encoded`. How to do that.